# Displaying progress bar within a powershell script

Tags: powershell, progress-bar

When I run the following PowerShell commands in a PowerShell console:

```
Mount-WindowsImage
Add-WindowsPackage
Dismount-WindowsImage
```

A progress bar bar is displayed within the PowerShell console.

However, when I copy these commands into a PowerShell script Mount.ps1 - I do not get the same progress bar. Is there any way of getting the progress bar using the PowerShell script (.ps1) method?

Comment: What is the value of your `$ProgressPreference` variable? If it's set to `SilentlyContinue`, it will not display

Comment: The value is: `Continue`. "Continue: Displays the progress bar and continues with (Default) execution."